# Filtrar query mediante foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
Tabla 1        
----------
id
*fk_ciudades
datoX1
datoX2

Tabla 2
----------
idCiudades
nombreCiudades
```

Y quiero hacer una query que seleccione una de las filas de **Tabla 1**, cuando
una variable x que yo le pase, sea igual al nombre de una de las ciudades en **Tabla 2**. El problema es que no me doy idea de como construir el `WHERE` para lograr eso.

Pensé que poniendo `"WHERE *fk_ciudades = $varx"` era suficiente para referenciar a los nombres de las ciudades en Tabla2, pero no lo he logrado.
¿Es posible? ¿O estoy siendo víctima de un mal planeamiento de tablas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo este esquema simple. Lo puedes ampliar si quieres a provincias, países, etc. La consulta muestra las personas cuyo id_ciudad = 1 .

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/696039/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE personas
    (`id_persona` int, `nombre` varchar(150), `id_ciudad` int)
;

INSERT INTO personas
    (`id_persona`, `nombre`, `id_ciudad`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro', 1),
    (2, 'Santiago', 2),
    (3, 'Juan', 3),
    (4, 'Andrés', 1)


;

CREATE TABLE ciudades
    (`id_ciudad` int, `ciudad` varchar(150), `id_provincia` int)
;

INSERT INTO ciudades
    (`id_ciudad`, `ciudad`, `id_provincia`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Galilea', 1),
    (2, 'Betsaida', 2),
    (3, 'Patmos', 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  p.nombre, c.ciudad
FROM
  personas p
JOIN ciudades c
  ON p.id_ciudad=c.id_ciudad
WHERE p.id_ciudad=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/696039/1/0)**:

> ```
> | nombre |  ciudad |
> |--------|---------|
> |  Pedro | Galilea |
> | Andrés | Galilea |
> ```

Comment: Excelente explicación! Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de hacer el esquema!

Comment: @Aaren No olvides marcar la respuesta que te sirvió como solución, para que la pregunta no quede abierta.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, para poder hacer lo que deseas de:

> quiero hacer una query que seleccione una de las filas de Tabla 1, cuando una variable x que yo le pase, sea igual al nombre de una de las ciudades en Tabla 2.

Tienes que hacer un **JOIN**. Supongamos que quiero seleccionar la fila de acuerdo a la columna **id**, y supondre tambien que es de tipo **numerico**. Tambien supongo que las columnas con llaves, en la tabla1 es ***fk_ciudades** y en la tabla2 es **idCiudades**

```
SELECT id.Tabla1 
FROM Tabla1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.[*fk_ciudades]=Tabla2.[idCiudades]
WHERE Tabla2.nombreCiudades='nombre de la ciudad que le pases'
```

Debe estar correctamente relacionado las tablas para hacer esta operacion, esta de mas decir.

Comment: Justamente lo que necesitaba! Muchisimas gracias, TwoDent!