# Consulta MySQL de 2 tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla cliente:

```
id nombre idCiudad
```

La tabla ciudad:

```
id nombre
```

¿Como puedo hacer una select para que me muestre todo lo que hay en la tabla cliente pero en vez de sacarme el idCiudad me muestre directamente el nombre de esa ciudad?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene la misma respuesta aquí: [Filtrar query mediante foreign key](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50316/29967) Podrás ver un [esquema completo en SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/696039/1) Sólo tendrías que cambiar el nombre de las tablas y los valores que haga falta.

Comment: Ademas de que es duplicada, existen muchos tutoriales de sql en internet donde puedes buscar como relacionar 2 tablas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes realizar un `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT ciudad.nombre FROM ciudad INNER JOIN cliente ON cliente.id = ciudad.id
```